# what encoding are files after being dumped by nutch?

Tags: nutch

I have been using the readseg function to dump data after crawling with nutch. But I have been having encoding issues. What encoding are the files after being dumped by nutch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML content is still in the original encoding. Starting with Nutch 1.17 it can be optionally converted to UTF-8, see [NUTCH-2773](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2773). You need to set the property `segment.reader.content.recode` to true. Of course, this will not work for binary document formats.

All other data (metadata, extracted plain-text) is always encoded in UTF-8 when segments are dumped.